# Kafka streams re-partitioning skews data to single partition - causing performance issues

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a usecase in which I have to count number of events based on a parameter in payload value

Data in stream is something like
Key -> String (distinct and can scale well and unique)
Value -> json (has alot of fields and one field is date, which is same for large chunk)

Now I have to count records based on common date field

Problem is

When i repartition stream based on new key (date field), by using groupby or map or selectkey operation, Followed by an aggregation.

I end up having all messages in a stream skewed onto one partition in repartition topic

Which in a way hampers performance

And impact is exponentially increasing with number of data on stream with same same date

Is there any better alternative to this usecase?

#Kafkastream

When i repartition stream based on new key (date field), by using groupby or map or selectkey operation, Followed by an aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka, it is very obvious that grouping based on a key and all the subsequent events with the same key fall into the same partition (by default), as a result only one consumer instance going to read all events, and the performance issue as expected.

I don't think so the date field will be an ideal candidate for your grouping, as you may have many events on the same day, instead you can use any other unique field.

On a bonus, you can refer Kafka's source code for word histogram demo sample and alter your requirement accordingly.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.6/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/wordcount/WordCountDemo.java

Comment: Have a need to count for a date
Hence the key is bound to be that, for any aggregation

Comment: Is global ktable a solution to this?

Comment: One more alternative --> is using Processor Api with process function which will change key -- faster than a repartition topic or groupby (DSL)